# Why does my HTTP listener program works as Windows Form project but not in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, sockets, service

I created a simple asynchronous server using sockets, that listens for HTTP requests and calls the function `RequestCallback()` every time a request is received on a certain IP address and port.

It works when I run it in a Windows Forms project, but when I add the code to a Windows Service project, it runs but doesn't call `RequestCallback()`. See the two calls to `Log.Write()` below.

The service runs as a Network Service (Services > *Log On As* = "Network Service"), and I cannot change this; it is determined by the customer. I tried temporarily changing the service to log in as a Local User but the second log statement was still not being written.

```
class http_listener
{
   bool _stop; 

   main ()
    { 
        _stop = false;

        _eventListenerThread = new Thread(ListenForEvents);
        _eventListenerThread.Name = "Event listener thread";
        _eventListenerThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForEvents()
    {
        Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
        System.Net.EndPoint endPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8000);
        _socket.Bind(endPoint);
        _socket.Listen(1000);

        while (!_stop)
        { 
            Log.Write("this shows up in log every 2 seconds, even when run as service");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            _recvBufSize = 1000; // max bytes to recieve
            _begAcceptResult = _socket.BeginAccept(null, _recvBufSize, new AsyncCallback(RequestCallback), _socket);
        }
        _eventListenerThread = null;
    }

    private void RequestCallback(IAsyncResult begAcceptResult)
    {
        Log.Write("this is NOT written to log when run as service");
        Socket socket = (Socket)begAcceptResult.AsyncState;
        // write request packet to log 
        byte[] buf;
        int bytesTransferred;
        Socket endSocket = socket.EndAccept(out buf, out bytesTransferred, begAcceptResult);
        string stringTransferred = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, bytesTransferred);
        Log.Write(stringTransferred);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. For some reason the port was blocked by Windows Firewall when I ran my server as a service, but it did not block it when I ran the server as a Forms application.

Here is the setting I changed:

Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules > (right-click name of service) > Properties > "Protocols and Ports" tab > Local port > added 8000 to the port(s) already listed there

Comment: The first time you ran it from visual studio you most likely got a popup asking to allow it, which you obviously aren't going to get from a service.  Also note that `HTTPListener` is an actual thing, which threw me for a second.